# Difficulties deploying bot to Heroku

Tags: java, maven, gradle, heroku, discord

I am completely new to this so pretty much clueless and need help.

I have done a few things involving setting up a pom.xml file and Procfile, but whether that's working and the file hierarchy is correct is also kind of a mystery to me...

Anyway, when I deploy to Heroku, this is the error message I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project TokenBot1.0: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.example:TokenBot1.0:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: net.dv8tion:JDA:jar:4.2.0_214, com.jagrosh:jda-utilities:jar:3.0.4: Could not find artifact net.dv8tion:JDA:jar:4.2.0_214 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

I also don't understand maven vs. gradle all that much, but I think my project was using gradle initially, and then I followed a guide to try setup with maven since a lot of the Heroku guides wanted maven.

Files look something like this:

TokenBot 1.0

- Procfile
- build.gradle
- .git
- src

  - pom.xml
  - main
- build

  - libs

    - .jar file

Procfile

```
worker: java -jar target/TokenBot 1.0-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>TokenBot1.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0_214</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jagrosh</groupId>
            <artifactId>jda-utilities</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Please let me know if you need to know anything else.

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA#download read the readme?

Comment: @Minn how does this readme help me host a bot on heroku?

Comment: The problem is maven not heroku

Comment: @Minn ok what do you think the problem is with Maven?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I remade my whole project (just salvaged the code) using maven instead of gradle since basically every tutorial I could find used maven.

Next I made sure that I could still run my bot fine locally (I had to do a bit to my pom.xml file to achieve that)

The only tutorial I found that matched my exact case for deploying to heroku (minus github) was this Russian one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LRapMfUMe4s

After following this tutorial exactly, the only thing that was missing for me was to create a Procfile, which I did. Once that's done, head over to heroku and enable the dyno that should show up.

So basically:

1. Create a fresh project file using maven instead of gradle
2. Make sure it runs fine locally (both with 'run' button in IntelliJ and executing the .jar file)
3. Deploy to heroku following the video/journey above
4. Procfile; make sure to create one in your root folder

Comment: I don't see how this answers your question. in your question, you have a problem with one maven dependency not being found on central. this does not help.